# Firebase iOS 11 Ask for user notifications after button push

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase to enable push notifications on iOS 11.  I'm trying to ask the user's notification permission only AFTER a button is pushed.

Currently, the app asks for the users permission immediately on load.  I want to ask this permission in the `EnableNotificationViewController.swift` class after a button is pushed.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FBSDKCoreKit
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        // [START set_messaging_delegate]
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self


        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    // MARK: - Notifications

    // The callback to handle data message received via FCM for devices running iOS 10 or above.
    func application(received remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print(remoteMessage.appData)
    }


}
```

**EnableLocationViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Spring
import Firebase

class EnableNotificationsViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: DesignableLabel!

    // MARK: - View Did Load
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    // MARK: - Actions
    @IBAction func notificationButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you will need to move the remote notification permission request into a method in AppDelegate and then call this method from your ViewController that is called `EnableNotificationsViewController`.

lets start from `AppDelegate` and adding `registerAPNSServicesForApplication` method:

```
///- register with APNS
func registerAPNSServicesForApplication(_ application: UIApplication,withBlock block: @escaping (_ granted:Bool) -> (Void)) {

    // [START register_for_notifications]
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {granted, error in

                if granted == true{

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                    }

                    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

                }

                block(granted)
        })

    } else {

        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    }

}
```

And then from your `EnableNotificationsViewController` call the method in AppDelegate to request the permission, And just so you know that iOS 10 and up you will have completion block of the permission if its granted or not and i made it so it will be returned in completion block into your view controller, but not for iOS 9 and below, You'll need a special handling:

```
// MARK: - Actions
@IBAction func notificationButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let myApplication = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    myApplication.registerAPNSServicesForApplication(UIApplication.shared) { (granted) -> (Void) in

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

            if granted {

            }else {

            }

        }else {

            // will not be returned because iOS 9 has no completion block for granting the permission it will require special way.

        }

    }

}
```

To be honest i don't have device with iOS 9 to simulate completion block, but i think the users for iOS 9 and below are just 10% according to [Apple Analytics for November 2017](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/)

That should do it :)

Comment: Nope all good couldn't figure this out for a day so thanks ;)

Comment: Hey ! Your answer is really good, I had the same problem. However, I would like tu push a ViewController when the user has made his choice. Do you know how I could do this @Aaoli ?

Comment: @KevinB Hey, add it inside the granted block but only for iOS 10 and later.

Comment: @AaoIi that's what I dit, but nothing happen :/

Comment: @KevinB is it possible to show me how are you doing that’s ?

Comment: @AaoIi sure ! I did this : https://codeshare.io/5wl7m7 (The print is well called, but the view is not changed)

Comment: @KevinB are you sure that this method is being called ? Are u getting any warning or something in the console ?

Comment: I think so, because the print is well called. And I don't have any error in console

Comment: @KevinB may I have a sample of the project so I can help you better ?